# Should NHibernate generate SQL for GUID parameter without quotes?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, guid, generated-sql

Sql Server 2008 R2 Express. NHibernate 2.1.2.4.

I get SQL like:

```
SELECT customer0_.Id as Id1_0_ 
FROM customers customer0_ 
WHERE customer0_.Id=@p0;
@p0 = 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```

...which returns 0 records even though there is Customer in there with that Id.

The SQL Server column datatype is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

`<session-factory>` configured as follows:

```
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
```

Class's `<id>` configured as follows

```
<id name="_id" column="Id" type="Guid" access="field" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" >
  <generator class="guid.comb" />
</id>
```

Forging my way through this for the first time, w/ the help of various tuts. I've been over everything several times but no joy. Any ideas what is wrong/missing here?  TYIA!

Comment: Resolved: problem was actually caused by bad test data! I was misled by the fact that I couldn't get it to work with manually written SQL without quotes or a CAST/CONVERT, but evidently there is some magic that makes this unnecessary when parameters are expanded. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *seems* correct.  According to [this](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/use-guid-comb-in-your-database-if-you-need-guid-keys-but-don-t-want-to-take-a-big-performance-hit/) "we must remember that a Guid is not a string even thought that's how we see them.  A Guid is a 16-byte data structure."  So I'm not sure why you are not getting back the results you expect, but I think the generated SQL is correct in not having the quotes.